# What is responsible for starting the session bus in gdm3?

Tags: d-bus, session, gdm3

I'm trying to get gdm3 working on Alpine Linux, but it fails on finding the session bus. Specifically, this assertion fails: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/blob/40.4/src/wayland/meta-wayland.c#L370

This leads me to wonder, what is responsible for starting the session bus when using gdm3 exactly? I have the system bus running (which is not the same thing anyway).